# Problem with threading

Tags: list-manipulation

I've got the following:

```
list = {{{x11, y11}, {x12, y12}}, {{x21, y21}, {x22, y22}}}
```

The first element is a list of x/y data points. I want to divide each element of this list by the first element in the list. Then I want to do the same for the second list (and etc., for longer lists). This works:

```
Table[#/First[list[[i]]] & /@ list[[i]], {i, Length[list]}]
```

Shouldn't I be able to use Thread or MapThread or something, in order to clean this up? (So I don't have to refer to `list` three times?)

I'm not smart enough to do it. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ReplacePart` can specify the operation directly:

```
ReplacePart[list, {i_, j_} :> list[[i, j]] / list[[i, 1]]]
```

[image: result]

The `MapIndexed` equivalent is a little shorter, but perhaps also a little less readable:

```
MapIndexed[# / list[[#2[[1]], 1]] &, list, {2}]
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this is cleaner:

```
 twoListsOfPairs = {{{x11, y11}, {x12, y12}, {x13, y13}}, {{x21, y21}, {x22, y22}, {x23, y23}}};

 normalizeToFirst[list_] := Transpose[Transpose[list]/First[list]]

 normalizeToFirst /@ twoListsOfPairs
```

which returns:

```
 {{{1, 1}, {x12/x11, y12/y11}, {x13/x11, y13/y11}}, {{1, 1}, {x22/x21, y22/y21}, {x23/x21, y23/y21}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of threading, I believe you can use patterns which is much cleaner

`Replace[list, {i_, j_} -> {{1, 1}, j/i}, 1]`

Comment: This is awesome, but I'm not as familiar with patterns.